# Spring @RequestParam @DateTimeFormat positive offset not working

Tags: java, spring

I have the below controller for my rest API and it handles negative offset for timezone fine but it complains when i pass +ve offset

```
public ResponseEntity<?> findStages(@RequestParam(value = "from") @DateTimeFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ") DateTime from,
    @RequestParam(value = "to") @DateTimeFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ") DateTime to)
```

For example a "from" value of 2017-07-30T00:00:00.000-00:00 is parsed fine
but if i pass +ve offset like 2017-07-30T00:00:00.000+01:00, i get a MethodArgumentTypeMismatchException exception as "Failed to convert value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'org.joda.time.DateTime'"

Is it possible to set DateTimeFormat to accept positive offsets?

Comment: Could be the "+" sign causing problems. You may have to escape it.   see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1005676/urls-and-plus-signs

Comment: Thanks @MrSpoon that helped. using %2B parser the time fine. However when i pass time as 2017-07-30T00:00:00%2B01:00, i receive as 2017-07-29T16:00:00.000-07:00 in my controller, is it possible to retain the timezone sent?

Comment: Check here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16794772/joda-time-parse-a-date-with-timezone-and-retain-that-timezone
Looks like Joda is losing the timezone when you parse: shifting it into YOUR timezone instead.  There's a solution there that might work