# String datetime convert to LocalDateTime object

Tags: java, jodatime, android-jodatime

I want to convert to this string to `LocalDateTime` object. How can I do that?

**"Thu Aug 29 17:46:11 GMT+05:30 2019"**

I already try something, but it didn't work.

```
    final String time = "Thu Aug 29 17:46:11 GMT+05:30 2019";
    final String format = "ddd MMM DD HH:mm:ss 'GMT'Z YYYY";

    DateTimeFormatter dateTimeFormatter = DateTimeFormat.forPattern(format);
    LocalDateTime localDateTime = LocalDateTime.parse(time, dateTimeFormatter);
```

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid format: "Thu Aug 29 17:46:11"
>       at org.joda.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.parseLocalDateTime(DateTimeFormatter.java:900)
>       at org.joda.time.LocalDateTime.parse(LocalDateTime.java:168)

Comment: What makes you think `ddd` would match to `Thu`? Did you consider reading the [docs](https://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/format/DateTimeFormat.html)?

Comment: Oh... i read wrong documentation i think.... Thanks for ur help. I got the solution.

Comment: Why a `LocalDateTime` object? For most purposes it would be better to keep the GMT offset from the string (which a `LocalDateTime` doesn’t do; consider `DateTime`).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Note that Joda-Time is considered to be a largely “finished” project.
>   No major enhancements are planned. If using Java SE 8, please migrate
>   to `java.time` (JSR-310).

This is quoted from the Joda-Time home page. I should say that it endorses the answer by Basil Bourque. In any case if you insist on sticking to Joda-Time for now, the answer is:

```
    final String time = "Thu Aug 29 17:46:11 GMT+05:30 2019";
    final String format = "EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss 'GMT'ZZ YYYY";

    DateTimeFormatter dateTimeFormatter = DateTimeFormat.forPattern(format)
            .withLocale(Locale.ENGLISH)
            .withOffsetParsed();
    DateTime dateTime = DateTime.parse(time, dateTimeFormatter);
    System.out.println(dateTime);
```

Output:

> 2019-08-29T17:46:11.000+05:30

- In the format pattern string

  - You need `EEE` for day of week. `d` is for day of month.
  - You need lowercase `dd` for day of month; uppercase `DD` is for day of year
  - I have put in `ZZ` because according to the docs this is for offset with a colon; `Z` works in practice too
- Since Thu and Aug are in English, you need an English speaking locale. Since I believe your string comes from `Date.toString()` originally, which always produces English, I found `Locale.ROOT` appropriate.
- I found it better to parse into a `DateTIme`. To preserve the offset from the string we need to specify that through `withOffsetParsed()` (you can always convert to `LocalDateTime` later if desired).

### Links

- [Joda-Time home page](https://www.joda.org/joda-time/)
- Related question: [Joda Time parse a date with timezone and retain that timezone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16794772/joda-time-parse-a-date-with-timezone-and-retain-that-timezone)
- [Documentation of `org.joda.time.format.DateTimeFormat`](https://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/format/DateTimeFormat.html) with the format pattern letters including their case

Answer (score 4):

## tl;dr

FYI, the [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project is now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advising migration to the [*java.time*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes. See [Tutorial by Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html).

```
OffsetDateTime.parse( 
    "Thu Aug 29 17:46:11 GMT+05:30 2019" , 
    DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "EEE MMM d HH:mm:ss OOOO uuuu").withLocale( Locale.US ) 
)
.toString()
```

> 2019-08-29T17:46:11+05:30

## `LocalDateTime` cannot represent a moment

> "Thu Aug 29 17:46:11 GMT+05:30 2019"
>
> I want to convert to this string to LocalDateTime object.

You cannot.

- The input represents a moment, a specific point on the timeline.
- A `LocalDateTime` cannot represent a moment. A `LocalDateTime` has only a date and a time-of-day but lacks the context of a time zone or offset-from-UTC.

Trying to handle your input as a `LocalDateTime` would mean discarding valuable information. That would be like handling a amount of money as simply a `BigDecimal` while throwing away information about which currency.

## `OffsetDateTime`

You input string includes an [offset-from-UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTC_offset) of five and a half hours ahead. So parse as an [`OffsetDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/OffsetDateTime.html) object.

Define a custom formatting pattern to match your input, using the [`DateTimeFormatter`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html) class.

Define

```
String input = "Thu Aug 29 17:46:11 GMT+05:30 2019" ;
DateTimeFormatter f = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "EEE MMM d HH:mm:ss OOOO uuuu").withLocale( Locale.US );
OffsetDateTime odt = OffsetDateTime.parse( input , f ) ;
```

> odt.toString(): 2019-08-29T17:46:11+05:30

Tip: That input format is *terrible*. Educate the publisher of those input string about the standard [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) for practical date-time formats.

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

You may exchange *java.time* objects directly with your database. Use a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) compliant with [JDBC 4.2](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/170) or later. No need for strings, no need for `java.sql.*` classes.

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), [**Java SE 10**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_10), [**Java SE 11**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_11), and later  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.

  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Most of the *java.time* functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android bundle implementations of the *java.time* classes.
  - For earlier Android (<26), the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) (mentioned above). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

Answer (score 1):

The format string you provided for parsing doesn't looks right with the text format you've actually got. You need to parse first, then format. Just test below code,

```
    SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss z yyyy",Locale.getDefault());
    Date dt = null;
    try {
        dt = format.parse("Thu Aug 29 17:46:11 GMT+05:30 2019");
        SimpleDateFormat out = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM dd, yyyy h:mm a");
        String output = out.format(dt);
        Log.e("OUTPUT",output);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: Why would you want to use the super old cumbersome legacy date API of java instead the modern date-time API? OP is also using jodatime already.

Comment: Because someone wants use old code with some modification instead of using large library.

Comment: The modern date-time library is part of Java since 8. It is not external. Your solution works and is good for Q&A but I would clearly mark it as legacy solution. Anyone having Java 8 or newer should use the modern API. There is no valid reason to not use it, except if you do not have Java 8.

Comment: Sorry, I'm talking about an Android